# Does type checking differ for return and when passed as arguement

Tags: c++, typechecking

Myself and my friend were trying two programs, First one where int& is returned, second one where int& is passed.

Program 1:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int& fun(int x)
{
    static int y=x;
    cout<<"Inside Fun()"<<y<<endl;
    return y;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<(fun(10)=30)<<endl;
    cout<<fun(40)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

works like a charm..

Whereas Program 2

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int& fun(int &x)
{
    static int y=x;
    cout<<"Inside Fun()"<<y<<endl;
    return y;
}
int main()
{
    cout<<(fun(10)=30)<<endl;
    cout<<fun(40)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

gives the error

```
return.cc: In function 'int main()':
return.cc:11: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int'
return.cc:3: error: in passing argument 1 of 'int& fun(int&)'
return.cc:12: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int&' from a temporary of type 'int'
return.cc:3: error: in passing argument 1 of 'int& fun(int&)'
```

In the first program, fun::&x = 30 is allowed in return . Whereas in Program 2, int &x =10 is not allowed. My doubt is whether stricter type checking is done in C++ for function parameters compared to return types and why is &x=10 not valid as a function parameter.

Comment: The code you've posted is different from the code you've described which is different from the code that generated those errors.

Comment: Sorry.. my bad. will correct it

Comment: @AlexeyAndronov wow. that seems to work.. But it would be nice if you can explain me the difference in both cases and why const was required as a parameter and same was not necessary for return type?

Comment: @erip. There is only one difference. fun(int x) is passed in the first program, where (int &x) is passed in second..

Answer (score 3):

A reference can't be bound to temporary or *literal* values, like the literal integer value `10` for example.

If you want a reference and bind it to a temporary or literal value you need to use a reference to a *constant*, i.e. `int const&`.

You don't need to return a reference to a constant in the second program because you don't return a reference to a temporary or literal value, you return a reference to an actual variable whose lifetime is the lifetime of the program.

For example:

```
int val = 10;
int& ref = fun(val);
```

In the above code, the variable `ref` is actually a reference to the static local variable `y` inside the function `fun`.

Comment: I understand this point now..When the return is done as int&, same action is being performed as passing a parameter, isn't it.. Correct me if i am wrong. Why is const not necessary there?

Comment: Does that mean, if i use fun(static int x), then the error in 2nd program can be avoided as well?

Comment: @CVS No, you can't have static arguments. In the second program you need `int& fun(int const& x)`

Comment: Another point i would like to make is, even if the variable y is not static, compiler is ok with giving a warning saying, scope of y is limited. whereas in the second case, i encounter an error. What is the difference, i am unable to be link

Comment: @CVS Warnings are things that the compiler thinks you are doing wrong, and often they are for things that will lead to *undefined behavior*. Always read and fix warnings.  And no you should not get linker errors, but you can get crashes when running your program, and that's because of the *undefined behavior*. That the two programs exhibit different behavior when run is because the behavior is undefined, and therefore you can't really predict it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert 10 to an int& because its a literal value.
Its nothing to do with the return type, its a fundamental flaw in your understanding of the parameter.  You could make the parameter a const int& and then that will work.

Comment: But the same thing happens, when int& is being returned. It assigns the value to return x, there const parameter is not required? Why this difference.

Comment: I'm sorry @CVS I don't understand what you are trying to say.  Neither of your programs return x;  I have run the code for program 2 and after changing it to a const int& it works fine.  Please can you show me code for what you mean?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.. I am trying to ask, in the first program, when fun(10) = 30 is called, it actually assigns the value 30 the static variable y in the manner fun::y=30 because int& is the return type. Why is that a const not necessary at this point.. Isn't this act as passing 10 to the parameter x in func(int& x)

Comment: Understand now - fun(10)=30; is bad code IMO.  But you are right that works, because you are doing int& = 30; int& is actually you static variable y within fun().  This works because you are not passing a literal as a parameter to fun() when you are doing int&=30.  You are really doing y=30.  I guess you are quite new to C++, here is what I would do to start with: 1. Always pass parameters as const references.  2. Never return references.  3. Make more use of the space bar and / key to format your code and add comments (for when you come back to it).

Comment: Sure.. i will take these suggestions seriously.. i understand, this is not a good practice, I am only trying to understand the difference here.. How one works and the other don't.. Is there a difference treatment/type checking for return/passing parameter. I am still not convinced with regard to the answer

Answer (score 1):

You have problems not with the returned int& but with int& in your parameter. Refernce type int& is a mutable reference while you trying to pass a literal int to it which obviously can't be mutated.

Comment: My question was, when fun() =30 is done,there also we are assigning a value to reference of x which is returned..What is the difference between passing and returning. Both seems same to me.

Comment: When you type `fun() =30` you are not assigning to a reference, you assign value to variable which is being referenced. In your case it's `static int y`.

Answer (score 0):

Pass-by-value will create a copy of the passed object with the expectation that that copy will die at the end of the function call.

Pass-by-reference will pass the actual object and you will be allowed to mutate it. Because you're passing a literal (10), you can't mutate it, so you need to pass a `const` reference.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.. Why the same does not apply to return type, when int&. actually when i do, fun()=30, it actually assigns the value 30 to x due to the return type int&. Here const is not required? It kind of confuses me.

Comment: I try to avoid returning references because it can be dangerous. If you return a reference to a local variable to the function, you will be returning a reference to an object that has been destroyed (i.e., a dangling reference). The reason it works in your case is because `y` has been declared `static`, and as such will live as long as the program.

Comment: Thanks erip for the explanation. I was more concerned about the const being mandated when passed as argument and not when returned.. Why this difference exists..

Comment: The second point in my answer explains this. You can't mutate a literal.